# Javac not working in cmd windows 10

Tags: java, windows

I have windows 10 and installed JDK 1.8.0_66 set the path for java on my cmd and javac response that there's no source files when i test it on some programs.
any suggestions?

Comment: Do you search before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the JDK bin to the system PATH, in Control Panel, System, Advanced, Environment Variables.

Comment: javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

This is the msg i get i did everything